# MAMP Pro 3.06 Postfix (Smart Host) not working on OSX Yosemite

Tags: postfix-mta, osx-yosemite, mamp-pro, smarthost

I can't seem to get the smart host in Mamp Pro to work with OSX Yosemite (with Postfix 2.1 preinstalled). After configuring MAMP with my mail server details in looks like Mamp is using old or unsupported settings in Postfix.

If I restore the original configuration and stop MAMP, running Postfix manually from terminal results in Postfix starting without any issues. If I start up MAMP and configure to my mail server settings and apply them, if I stop Mamp and then try to start postfix from terminal it fails to start and reports  **unused parameter: mydomain_fallback=localhost**, and fails to start.

If I edit the main.cf file for postfix and rem that line out, save main.cf and attempt to start postfix it tries to start and fails once again.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26447316/mac-os-x-10-10-yosemite-postfix-sasl-authentication-failed

Answer (score 5):

Find main.cf, and change.

**file:**
/Applications/MAMP PRO/MAMP PRO.app/Contents/Resources

**from:**

```
mydomain_fallback = localhost
```

**to:**

```
#mydomain_fallback = localhost
inet_protocols=ipv4
```

stop/start MAMP

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Works now. Thanks.

Comment: ThankyouThankyouThankyou…

Comment: This is break my mam pro to start