# Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite Postfix SASL authentication failed

Tags: email, smtp, postfix-mta, osx-yosemite, sasl

I followed the step described in the link below to setup my mac to send out email. 
http://www.anujgakhar.com/2011/12/09/using-macosx-lion-command-line-mail-with-gmail-as-smtp/

It was working fine on my Mac OS X 10.9. But after I upgraded to OS X 10.10. The mail.log showed the following error. What is the problem?

```
Oct 19 00:28:22 paullam-macbook-pro.local postfix/smtp[30383]: 6B47B8AD4E8: SASL authentication failed; cannot authenticate to server smtp.gmail.com[74.125.68.109]: generic failure
Oct 19 00:28:24 paullam-macbook-pro.local postfix/smtp[30383]: 6B47B8AD4E8: to=<zzpaul@gmail.com>, relay=smtp.gmail.com[74.125.68.108]:587, delay=3.4, delays=0.01/0/3.4/0, dsn=4.7.0, status=deferred (SASL authentication failed; cannot authenticate to server smtp.gmail.com[74.125.68.108]: generic failure)
```

Answer (score 97, accepted):

I had the same problem. A Google search turned up this link: http://hkitago.com/2014/09/yosemiteのpostfix設定/

It turned out I was missing the following line in /etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = plain
```

Comment: This took me hours to stumble onto this, but great find, and quick fix

Comment: Awesome answer. Thank you. I would have never figured this one out on my own.

Comment: All of you can read Japanese? For those of you find English easier to read, try [these instructions](http://www.iamafishnow.com/2014/11/02/set-up-smtp-gmail-to-work-with-php-mail-on-osx-yosemite/) instead. Also, I needed to turn on access for less secure apps within my Google account: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps.  Probably not a good idea in general, but Google would not send my emails otherwise. Turn off access when you're done testing.

Comment: Thank you @bergie3000 that "less secure apps" option was the missing piece of the puzzle for me. Thanks.

Comment: This and using Google App Password got me going on Sierra.  Thanks!

Comment: @a.brookshollar using Google App Password with this and still not working. Any thoughts?

Comment: If someone got a error message like 'SASL authentication failed' or 'Application-specific password required', so you maybe use 2 factor authentication in Google. Check this tutorial to solve this problem (sat a special app password):  https://davidwesterfield.net/2015/02/using-postfix-sasl-authentication-with-google-2-step-verification-on/

Answer (score 8):

I added both snippets as suggested, but still no luck. Then I found this article:

http://www.developerfiles.com/how-to-send-smtp-mails-with-postfix-mac-os-x-10-8/

and ran the following steps from it:

Step 2. Create the sasl_passwd file
We need to create the sasl_passwd file with the SMTP credentials

```
sudo vi /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

Write the following content exactly (don't put in your user address and password) and save:

`smtp.gmail.com:587 your_address@gmail.com:password`

Create the Postfix lookup table from the sasl_passwd file.

```
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

This will create the file sasl_passwd.db

Step 3. Restart Postfix
To apply all new changes we have to restart Postfix:

```
sudo postfix reload
```

And still no luck. But then I noticed that relayhost in /etc/postfix/main.cf

was commented out with brackets like so:

```
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
```

I changed this line to:

```
relayhost = smtp.gmail.com:587
```

reloaded postfix with:

```
sudo postfix reload
```

and postfix started sending email. Hooray!

Comment: Two problems with your answer: 1) You must enter your personal values for 'your_address' and 'password' in the step `smtp.gmail.com:587 your_address@gmail.com:password` 2) You misspelled `postfix` in the last step. Also, another thing I discovered - the key to everything, really - you must turn on access for lest secure apps in your Google account (https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps). **Do all of this at your own risk!!!**

Comment: Excellent link. Thank you @esod

Comment: Thanks @bergie3000 that sorted my issue.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out I needed another piece to get this to work.

```
sudo vi /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.postfix.master.plist
```

and right after this:

```
<dict>
```

add this:

```
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
<true/>
```

I can now send emails with Postfix on Yosemite!

Answer (score 0):

Answer by @Josh is working just fine (can lot leave comments on the answer), but using **login** as a filter would also work just fine. Not sure what the difference is, though.

As stated by the [documentation page](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter)